# Is there a way to define "% of column total" measure in DAX which would work dynamically for any dimension?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I need my measure `% of column total` to work with any dimension that is currently selected in the pivot columns.

I have this formula which works for dimension called Gender, but I need the formula to be general and work for any dimension currently selected. I am using this measure to calculate other measures.

```
Weighted Gender % :=
DIVIDE (
    'Dimensions'[Weigthed Base];
    CALCULATE ( 'Dimensions'[Weigthed Base]; ALLSELECTED ( 'Dimensions'[Gender] ) )
)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a general version of ALLSELECTED():

```
Weighted % :=
DIVIDE (
    'Dimensions'[Weigthed Base];
    CALCULATE ( 'Dimensions'[Weigthed Base]; ALLSELECTED () )
)
```

Be careful though, ALLSELECTED is a complex function, and you might get unexpected results depending on your data model:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-definitive-guide-to-allselected/